# How do I re-instantiate the date object in a variable?

Tags: javascript

So i have the below. It may not have the correct syntax because i had to remove a few lines but it works. It's just that I have to refresh the page for the counter to update.

Is there a way that the counter updates itself every one minute. The setInterval doesn't work because the loginDown new Date hasn't been instantiated again (the page hasn't refreshed) is there a way for loginDown to instantiate again every minute?

```js
function counter(hours, minutesLeft){
  alert(hours + minutesLeft);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var now = new Date();

  var loginDown = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(),now.getDate(), 15,10,0,0) - now;
  var date = new Date(loginDown);
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutesLeft = date.getMinutes();
  counter(hours,minutesLeft);
  setInterval(counter(hours,minutesLeft), 60000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: just a counter that updates itself. Also the counter is beced off of the variable value loginDown e.g. 10 minutes left... **updates itself**... 9 minutes left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The setInterval doesn't work because the loginDown new Date hasn't
>   been instantiated again (the page hasn't refreshed) is there a way for
>   loginDown to instantiate again every minute?

**No**, you are simply not passing the **function reference as a parameter**.

Make it

```
   setInterval(function(){counter(hours,minutesLeft)}, 60000);
```

Also, instantiate your date in the `counter` method itself.

```
function counter(){
   var now = new Date();
   var date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(),now.getDate(), 15,10,0,0) - now;
   var hours = date.getHours();
   var minutesLeft = date.getMinutes();
   alert(hours + minutesLeft);
}

$document.ready({
            setInterval(counter, 60000);
});
```

Comment: But `hours` is still unchanged. It should be changed before calling `counter`

Comment: `hours` and `minutesLeft` are still going to be the same though.

Comment: @Adelin why not instantiate the same in `counter` method itself.

Comment: @AurelBílý Yes, I had missed out on that earlier.

Comment: @gurvinder372 or that. The point was that 90% of the issue is that they were never changed

Comment: @Adelin Yes, but passing the return value of counter in setInterval wasn't helping either. Anyways, that is taken care of now.

Comment: I get that but I need to keep the date instantiation in the document ready as it's used by something else i didn't show. However, there is the solution of duplicating the date and minutes left in the function but i was hoping for a all in one sort of thing

Comment: You can refactor that logic in a separate method and invoke the same from 2 places... anyways `document.ready` will only be able to use first instance of that date since rest of those dates will be generated next time when setInterval's callback will be executed.